# Property does not get updated from inside block

Tags: objective-c, properties, objective-c-blocks, firebase

I have this snippit from a class to fetch something:

```
interface:
@property (nonatomic, strong) Firebase *firebase;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *offlineCopy


implementation:
//...connection code...\\

- (void)offlineCopyForEvent:(NSString *)event {
    [self.firebase observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        if ([snapshot.value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary *copy = snapshot.value;

            self.offlineCopy = [copy mutableCopy];

            NSLog(@"%@", copy);
        }

    }];
}
```

The data is correctly returned (the log shows the results). But when I try to access the property after it has been set using the code above, it returns nil. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The method does not set the property. It hands `self.firebase` a block, in which the property is set. `self.firebase` likely executes that block asynchronously at a later time, after the `-offlineCopyForEvent:` returned.

Comment: I can verify that the `NSLog` in the block gets executed before the readout of the property. The property should've been set by then, right?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
- (void)offlineCopyForEvent:(NSString *)event {
    __weak YourViewController weakSelf = self;
    self.offlineCopy = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [self.firebase observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        if ([snapshot.value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary *copy = snapshot.value;

            weakSelf.offlineCopy = [copy mutableCopy];

            NSLog(@"%@", copy);
        }

     }];
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The property offlineCopy contains no data after the block fired...

Comment: This block likely execute asynchoronously for this time. You could try NSLog(@"%@", weakSelf.offlineCopy) for see this value. You have to make sure that you call back to get "offlineCopy" when this block Completion

Comment: I know the block is executed asynchronously... The property offlineCopy does not get set... It remains the same as before the block is executed...